# Como usar unidade de tempo menor que milissegundos em um setInterval ou setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber (se for possível) como usar uma unidade de tempo menor que a de milissegundos nas funções `setInterval` ou `setTimeout`.

Fiz um cronômetro progressivo usando o seguinte código

```
function timer(){
    if(counter < qntLinhas){
        counter++;
        $("#quantidade").text(counter);
    }
    if(counter > qntLinhas){
        counter -= 1;
        $("#quantidade").text(counter);
    }
}

setInterval("timer()", 0);
```

A variável `qntLinhas` é referente ao resultado de uma consulta AJAX que me retorna um valor X.

Funciona muito bem, no entanto, quando o valor de qntLinhas é muito alto, demora um pouco até chegar no resultado final e, chega ser chato esperar.

Para burlar isso, fiz dois incrementos seguidos na variável counter, mas além de ser gambiarra, o resultado final não é preciso.

Tentei usar o plugin [countTo](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo) e a questão do tempo foi resolvida, porém, outro problema surgiu. Ele não me permite atualizar o valor, que eu quero atingir na contagem, em tempo de execução (via AJAX).

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a ideia de cronometro progressivo e como isso deve interagir com o ajax? para ser sincero não percebo qual é o problema que estás a tentar resolver

Comment: Por que está usando 0 no timer? É só por o valor desejado lá. Por exemplo 60000 para um minuto.

Comment: http://clayderson.com.br/ da uma olhada nessa página, você vai entender. o valor final do contador é definido em tempo de execução com ajax. Aquele cronometro é atualizado a cada 30 segundos com um novo valor (se for o caso).

Comment: @Bacco, eu quero um valor menor que 0 milissegundos, não maior.

Comment: Se quiser só a resposta para o que perguntou, é simples: "não tem como". Mas eu tenho quase certeza que o problema não é no timer, só que fica dificil ajudar sem você explicar o problema que tem que ser resolvido, em vez do jeito que você está achando que vai solucionar. Sugestão de leitura: [O que é o problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/). Uma vez que soubermos o problema, podemos propor soluções sem precisar do timer menor que milissegundos.

Comment: PS: Se é o contador do comment, é mais simples ainda, é só não contar de 1 em 1, e fazer uma curva exponencial pra ficar legal (começando pular uma quantidade maior, e diminuindo o intervalo ao chegar perto do valor). E neste caso, edite a pergunta e acrescente este detalhe, pois no comment normalmente os visitantes não vão ficar procurando detalhes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta já foi respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102173/70), e já recebeu meu +1. Vou complementar com esta resposta, que se refere ao problema real, que não foi postado inicialmente no corpo da pergunta.

Para o contador não demorar demais, fiz uma fórmula que calcula o passo de incremento conforme a distância que falta para chegar no valor total:

```js
var qntLinhas = 938203;
var counter = 0;

function timer(){
    if(counter < qntLinhas){
        counter += Math.min( Math.ceil( ( qntLinhas - counter ) / 10 ), counter + 1);
        $("#quantidade").text(counter);
        setTimeout("timer()", 50);
    }
}
timer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="quantidade"></div>
```

Para o processamento não ficar ocorrendo à toa, mudamos o `setInterval` para `setTimeout`, que só será chamado enquanto o contador precisar incrementar.

Ao completar o Ajax, basta chamar `timer()` para atualizar o contador.

Para ajustar o tempo, basta mexer no `/ 10` da fórmula, e não no `setTimeOut`. A divisão da fórmula ajusta a velocidade do contador sem necessidade de sobrecarregar o processamento da página com timeout menor.

### Teste com valores muito diferentes

Esse aqui eu postei apenas como teste, para mostrar como a fórmula se adapta a valores bem diferentes, com pouca diferença entre as finalizações:

```js
var qntLinhas1 = 1003;
var qntLinhas2 = 389041;
var qntLinhas3 = 93820317;
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var counter3 = 0;

function timer(){
   if(counter1 < qntLinhas1) counter1 += Math.min( Math.ceil( ( qntLinhas1 - counter1 ) / 10 ), counter1 + 1);
   if(counter2 < qntLinhas2) counter2 += Math.min( Math.ceil( ( qntLinhas2 - counter2 ) / 10 ), counter2 + 1);
   if(counter3 < qntLinhas3) counter3 += Math.min( Math.ceil( ( qntLinhas3 - counter3 ) / 10 ), counter3 + 1);
   $("#quantidade1").text(counter1);
   $("#quantidade2").text(counter2);
   $("#quantidade3").text(counter3);
   if(counter1 < qntLinhas1 || counter2 < qntLinhas2 || counter3 < qntLinhas3) setTimeout("timer()", 50);
}
timer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quantidade1"></div>
<div id="quantidade2"></div>
<div id="quantidade3"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado e desculpa o modo como lhe respondi hoje a tarde, errei.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira fique tranquilo, acho que foi só um problema de comunicação dos dois lados. Quanto as dicas minhas e dos outros colegas, é sempre para te ajudar a formular as perguntas para aumentar a chance de respostas boas. Se tiver alguma duvida ou precisar de algum ajuste, melhoria ou explicação, basta comentar aqui que eu vejo se consigo ajudar.

Answer (score 6):

O corpo da sua pergunta exprime uma dúvida diferente da presente do título. Esta resposta é referente ao título.

**Não é possível**, a não ser que você reescreva o *handler* para programação de eventos em um engine como o *Chromium*, ao mesmo tempo forçando o *browser* a se comportar fora dos padrões estipulados pela Mozilla e especificação HTML 5 (já que todas as interfaces, tanto de métodos quanto de retorno de valores, trabalham com milissegundos não fracionados.)

Fontes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimummaximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers